# I am not able to install Apache Airflow in Windows

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

My attempts include:

[ here i have python 3.9 so my constraints is 3.9]

1. I created a virtual environment and attempted to install Apache-Airflow by using pip install 'apache-airflow==2.5.1' / —constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.1/constraints-3.9.txt," but I received an error that I couldn't understand, so I looked on the stack community for advice and learned that I needed to add -t, which I did.
2. but then I started getting permission errors, then I went into community posts and how to fix permission errors, and it was suggested that I should run command prompt as administrator and then install unfortunately this thing isn't working for me
3. I've tried running cmd as administrator, going to my project's directory, activating virtualenv, and installing the library, but I still get the same problem. `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\\'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run airflow in docker? I find using docker environment much better when using linux on windows. There is a docker compose file for airflow in the GitHub repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the slash (/) from the command before the --constraint and then running inside the cmd terminal; it will work.

`pip install apache-airflow==2.5.1  --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.1/constraints-3.9.txt"`

Note : Please be aware that the above recommendation is for Windows, but even if it is successfully installed you won't be able to run airflow because of the files used, such as pwd and others. Therefore, I will recommend that you use airflow in Windows using Ubuntu. You can follow this link to install Ubuntu in your system and set up airflow.
[youtube-video-url](https://youtu.be/SYOUbiGtGiU)